# Cocoa: how can I add custom row in table? or other way?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode4.2

Is it possible to add different rows created in IB? What I mean is:
[image: Table with differrent rows]

**All rows should be created not programatically, but with pre-created with objects.

Or maybe is other way to do this?? maybe without table??

Comment: > **All rows should be created not programatically.
why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't create a table with pre-existing rows from within IB.

You can however create text and image based table rows in IB, and lay them out, but you then have to write the table delegate code to load these from the xib and add them to the table as an when required.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do this? on mac OSX, I seen on iOS, but not in OSX.

Comment: Search for Cell View in the IB library panel to find the cells.  Add them in the tableView:dataCellForTableColumn:row: delegate method.

Comment: Actually, if you use Storyboards (new in iOS 5), you can create a table with pre-existing rows in IB.